# Delete duplicated string in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have this result row from a query with GROUP_CONCAT:

clients, employees, employees, providers, providers

And i wanna get something like this:

clients, employees, providers

Please, i'm new here and i need your help, be pacient if the question is not well formed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `DISTINCT` option in `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT columnname), ...
```

Comment: adding `ORDER BY columname` (as part of the GROUP_CONCAT) would ensure the distinct values are listed in the requested order "clients", then "employees", then "providers".

Comment: @Barmar, thank you very much! worked totally as I needed, I was trying with "Distinct" but I put it before group_concat

Answer (score 0):

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

> array_unique — Removes duplicate values from an array
>
> array array_unique ( array $array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_STRING ] )

maybe this is what you need:

```
$row = array_unique($row);
```

Edit: If I am not mistaken, sql returns the results as a key value array, so I think this is what you want.

Edit2: Do this:

```
$row = explode(",", $response);
$row = array_unique($row);
```

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()` combines the results into a single column as a comma-separated string.

Comment: This is not necessarily a PHP question, and you're using a PHP function.

Comment: Yes, I am not an SQL master, but I believe my Edit2 solves this problem.

Comment: I needed the result from mysql, but thanks anyway c: